# Visit visa UK Email for further documents

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

it is been a week since I submitted my parents visit visa application.

They have requested the sponsor's bank statement and job letter.

Are there any signs of approval or refusal?

Comment: In general, no; it simply suggests that the application lacks some supporting documents, without which a decision cannot be made. If you are sponsoring them, your financial and employment information should have been provided, as indicated in the [UK guide to supporting documents](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf)

Comment: I imagine they could have refused the application at this point for failure to provide the relevant supporting documents. So while contact from them doesn’t indicate a negative or a positive outcome, it does show they are making an effort to assess the application fairly.

Comment: This is typically a favorable sign. You should submit the documents as soon as possible. Albeit it would have been better to have submitted them with the original application, it means only that the decision, whatever it is, is merely delayed.

Answer (score 3):

We did submit the requested documents and more within the time frame given in the email.      Yet the visa was refused given back to us in the next week.